# django using .extra() got error `only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression`

Tags: sql, django

I'm trying to use `.extra()` where the query return more than 1 result, like :

`'SELECT "books_books"."*" FROM "books_books" WHERE "books_books"."owner_id" = %s' % request.user.id`

I got an error : `only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression`

Try it on dev-server using sqlite3. Anybody knows how to fix this? Or my query is wrong?

EDIT:

I'm using [django-simple-ratings](https://github.com/coleifer/django-simple-ratings), my model like this :

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    #
    #
    ratings = Ratings()
```

I want to display each `Thread`'s ratings and whether a user already rated it or not. For 2 items, it will hit 6 times, 1 for the actual `Thread` and 2 for accessing the `ratings`. The  query:

```
    threads = Thread.ratings.order_by_rating().filter(section = section)\
                .select_related('creator')\
                .prefetch_related('replies')

    threads = threads.extra(select = dict(myratings = "SELECT SUM('section_threadrating'.'score') AS 'agg' FROM 'section_threadrating' WHERE 'section_threadrating'.'content_object_id' = 'section_thread'.'id' ",)
```

Then i can print each `Thread`'s ratings without hitting the db more. For the 2nd query, i add :

```
   #continue from extra 
   blahblah.extra(select = dict(myratings = '#####code above####',
                                voter_id = "SELECT 'section_threadrating'.'user_id' FROM 'section_threadrating' WHERE ('section_threadrating'.'content_object_id' = 'section_thread'.'id' AND 'section_threadrating'.'user_id' = '3') "))
```

Hard-coded the `user_id`. Then when i use it on template like this :

```
{% ifequal threads.voter_id user.id %}
#the rest of the code
```

I got an error : `only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression`

Let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: Could you post your actual code please? The examples in the Django documentation are of this form `Entry.objects.extra(select={stuff})` which is not what the code above looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the query. Generally, when you are writing subqueries, they **must** return only 1 result. So a subquery like the one `voter_id`:

```
select ..., (select sectio_threadrating.user_id from ...) as voter_id from ....
```

is invalid, because it can return more than one result. If you are sure it will always return one result, you can use the `max()` or `min()` aggregation function:

```
blahblah.extra(select = dict(myratings = '#####code above####',
                             voter_id = "SELECT max('section_threadrating'.'user_id') FROM 'section_threadrating' WHERE ('section_threadrating'.'content_object_id' = 'section_thread'.'id' AND 'section_threadrating'.'user_id' = '3') "))
```

This will make the subquery always return 1 result.

Removing that hard-code, what user_id are you expecting to retrieve here? Maybe you just can't reduce to 1 user using only SQL.